# Is frame background considered a face?

Tags: frames, faces, rendering

I would like to know if Emacs treats empty portions of the frame as faces. I want to know because I wonder if the background of an Emacs frame is drawn separately of other elements on the screen.

EDIT: I have done some experiments and found that on X11, Emacs uses the function "x_clear_area" to fill in the background color of empty potions of the frame. Background for spaces and non-visible characters is handled by the draw method of the "font_driver" struct (xfont_draw/xftfont_draw).

EDIT2: Now I am very confused, there seem to be multiple places where the background is being drawn. Does anybody know where are all the places this happens on X11 build ?

Comment: Emacs draws rows during `update_window` using a combination of the data stored in the window's `desired_matrix` and `current_matrix` -- reusing whatever has not changed since the previous redisplay.  As to unused area at the end of the glyph row before reaching the window edge, Emacs makes a decision what face to extend to the window edge.  A GUI frame can have a parameter known as `background-color`, which is equivalent to the `default` face `:background` attribute:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/draft/manual/html_node/elisp/Font-and-Color-Parameters.html#Font-and-Color-Parameters

Comment: Thank you, I was very confused browsing the Emacs source code. Just to make sure, does this mean Emacs treats empty potions of the frame equally to any other ?

Comment: I am familiar with `extend_face_to_end_of_line` in `xdisp.c` in terms of filling the gap between the end of the text area of a glyph row and the end of the display line ....  Other than the general case where the color has been filled in by the above-mentioned function, I am unaware of a special use-case for the gap between the end of a glyph row and the end of the display line.  Perhaps another forum participant can think of an example ...  There is a left margin area and a right margin area, and there are fringes ... https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Sizes.html

Comment: See the Elisp manual, node [Font and Color Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Font-and-Color-Parameters.html). You can customize option `default-frame-parameters` to set the default background color you want.

Comment: Sometimes you can get useful information from `C-u C-x =` (which gives you face under point), unfortunately, faces can be overlayed, but this will only give you the topmost one.

Comment: I am trying to write a different renderer for emacs. Maybe in OpenGL or maybe as a module from rust which goes well with emacs. Unfortunately or fortunately I still have a long road ahead :).

Comment: I guess I have to implement the "redisplay_interface" and load all the function pointers from rust.